# Double genitive relative clause with cui?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I have stumbled upon different possible meanings of the construction di + article + 'cui' + noun.

One possible usage is:

> La donna della cui bellezza ho sentito parlare è alta.

Is it also possible to construct another kind of double-genitive such as in:
The woman, the name of whose cat is "Charlie", is tall.

> La donna, il nome del cui gatto è Charlie, è alta.

> John, il significato del cui nome è...

Is this construction grammatically correct? If yes, does it have a name? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: I’d probably rephrase as: “La Donna, il cui gatto si chiama Charlie, è alta” and “John, il cui nome significa...”

Comment: I am not sure it has a name per se: it's an assemblage of building blocks of Italian language. You could well use _cui_ together with other prepositions (_l'uomo al cui cospetto tremano tutti_), for instance. In itself, it's not logically different from using two specifications (_il nome del gatto della donna..._).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it has a name per se: it's an assemblage of building blocks of Italian language. You could well use *cui* together with other prepositions (*l'uomo al cui cospetto tremano tutti* or *la casa sul cui tetto c'è un'antenna*), for instance.

In itself, this “double genitive” is not logically different from using two specifications, with nouns (*il nome del gatto della donna...*) or an adjective (*il nome del suo gatto*). It happens in other languages too: a quick Google Books search yields sentences such as “The annexed letter from a friend (of whose judgment I have the highest opinion)...”

Answer (score -1):

It is correct and it is called "complemento di specificazione".
You can check for instance:  https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/cui.